# Handle exception in pyserial during disconnection

Tags: python, exception, pyserial

I have code which read data from serial port.

```
try: 
  dataIn = self.port.read(100) 
except serial.SerialException: 
  #do some work
  return None
```

If I disconnect device I catch exception which I can't handle someway.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 475, in read
    raise SerialException('device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)')
serial.serialutil.SerialException: device reports readiness to read but returned no data (device disconnected or multiple access on port?)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/katkov/work/obd2rds/obd2rds/testing/python/main.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/katkov/work/obd2rds/obd2rds/testing/python/main.py", line 41, in main
    dataIn = serPort.read()
  File "/home/katkov/work/obd2rds/obd2rds/testing/python/uart.py", line 55, in read
    dataIn = self.port.read(100)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 480, in read
    if e[0] != errno.EAGAIN:
TypeError: 'SerialException' object does not support indexing
```

How can I catch exception that it is processed properly.
Thanks!

Comment: As far as I'm aware, pySerial does not support python 3.4, which you are using here. So you'll need to either use a different library for your needs or rewrite your code in python 2.7. I recommend finding a different library.

Comment: As noted [here](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial.html#requirements) python3.x is available.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for [Jonathan Eunice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/240490/jonathan-eunice)! Your advice fixed my issue.

Now I use following code:

```
try:
    dataIn = self.port.read()
except serial.SerialException as e:
    #There is no new data from serial port
    return None
except TypeError as e:
    #Disconnect of USB->UART occured
    self.port.close()
    return None
else:
    #Some data was received
    return dataIn
```

Answer (score 3):

You aren't sharing your complete code, but if you're trying to index out your error number, that's not going to work AFAIK. Try:

```
try: 
  dataIn = self.port.read(100) 
except serial.SerialException as e:
  # ...
  if e.errno != errno.EAGAIN:
  # ...
```

Also, if you are doing work inside an exception handler that may lead to further exceptions, then nest the handlers. E.g.:

```
try: 
  dataIn = self.port.read(100) 
except serial.SerialException as e:
  try:
    # more dangerous stuff
  except serial.SerialException as e2:
    # handle nested expression
```

Comment: Unfortunately no one of your advice helped.

Comment: The code you posted still has `if e[0] != errno.EAGAIN:`. Your error message says `TypeError: 'SerialException' object does not support indexing`. `e[0]` is still indexing.

Comment: Sorry, that I haven't noted that read(self, size=1) function is from pyserial package: file serialposix.ry. It isn't mine.

Comment: Well, according to the error message, some code is trying to index into a non-indexable type (`SerialException`). Find where that happens, work backwards.

Comment: This happens in pyserial file serialposix.ry AFAIK.

Comment: Then trap it in a `try: ... except TypeError as e: ...` block. If the exception is flowing out of a black box, you can still capture it.